# How to copy from iCloud Photos to iCloud Drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, icloud, photos

If I store photos in iCloud Photos, it gets stored on my Mac locally, even when I try removing the options of not storing iCloud Photos, it gets stored. I want to know if there are any ways to copy the photos from iCloud Photos to iCloud Drive.

[image: Photos settings on my Mac]

[image: Storage on local Mac that gets downloaded from iCloud Photos]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255415/how-to-store-icloud-photo-library-only-in-the-cloud?rq=1 Basically, iCloud is a synchronisation solution, not a storage solution.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve turned off iCloud Photos, so now all your photos from when it was enabled are stored locally. Turn it back on to use Optimise Mac Storage and reduce the space required on your Mac.